# Sorting column in R data frame by date: Fails after 1999

Tags: r, sorting, date

The original data frame in R contains a column called `OrdDate` with values representing dates including 12/31/1999, 1/1/2007, and so on (over 230,000 of them) ranging from years 1999-2010.

However, when I apply date ordering with R code (follows) to the data frame, the dates sort correctly for those in 1999, but do not starting with 1/1/year, displaying 1/1/2009 next, before dates like 1/1/2004 and 1/2/2000.

Any ideas what I could do to enforce the correct date sorting on this column?

R code:

```
    sorted_frame<-frame1[order(as.Date(frame1$OrdDate, format="%m/%d/%y")),]
```

Comment: Try with `Y`instead of `y`for the year as `Y`is a 4-digit year and `y`a 2-digit

Comment: you may also want to try sort() instead of order()

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this :

```
a<-c("12/31/2010","12/31/1999","12/31/2008","12/31/1998")
```

Using `y`will fail as it is a 2-digit year:

```
 order(as.Date(a,format="%m/%d/%y"))
[1] 2 4 1 3
```

That is because you have :

```
as.Date(a,format="%m/%d/%y")
[1] "2020-12-31" "2019-12-31" "2020-12-31" "2019-12-31"
```

Using `Y` will achieve what you want because it is a 4-digit year:

```
order(as.Date(a,format="%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] 4 2 3 1
```

As R analyst pointed out, using `sort` might be a better solution as it returns your values as Dates for R :

```
a[order(as.Date(a,format="%m/%d/%Y"))]
[1] "12/31/1998" "12/31/1999" "12/31/2008" "12/31/2010"

sort(as.Date(a,format="%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] "1998-12-31" "1999-12-31" "2008-12-31" "2010-12-31"
```